# Django: in views how can a redirect if the paramater(linked to a url pattern) does not match a model result?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I apologize am still learning django and am just hitting my head on a wall with some of it.
The current issue is that I have a view linked through a URL parameter the issue and it works for showing my model info but if you hard type the url to a different parameter it shows the page. I have tried to redirect it but that is not working I feel like it might because of how and where I return my render. Any advice on how to set up url's base off model and if that model info doesn't exist either through a 404 or redirect to a different page?

View:

```
@login_required(login_url='login_register')
def project_page(request, name):
  project = Project.objects.all()
  issueticket1 = Issue.objects.filter(related_project__name__exact=name)
  table = IssueTable(issueticket1)
  project_list = {}
  for p in project:
      if p.name == name:
          project_list = {'id': p.project_id, 'startdate': p.start_date,
                          'enddate': p.end_date, 'description': p.description}
return render(request, 'main_projects.html', {'name': name, 'project_list': project_list, 'project': project, 'table': table})
```

Urls:

```
path('projects/<str:name>/', views.project_page, name="project_page"),
```

Comment: I have tried a few if statements in the for and outside of it to redirect but they do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what your exact goal is, it's not very clear to me so I'm guessing
here.
But the best thing to do when an object doesn't exist when getting an object is to return a 404 not found error message.

So in your code you're basically getting all projects and using if statements to check if they match the name.
Which can be quite expensive for the database and aside that looping through all the projects is not advisable, imagine you had 1000 projects in your database it means you're going through each one of them and checking if the name matches that will prevent the page from loading quickly.

What you can do instead is to use the filter method, and retrieve all projects matching the name.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


@login_required(login_url='login_register')
def project_page(request, name):
    project_list = Project.objects.all()
    issueticket1 = Issue.objects.filter(related_project__name__exact=name)
    table = IssueTable(issueticket1)

    # Instead of looping get the projects get the matching item, you can use get_object_or_404 from django
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, name=name)
    # or an alternative 
    try:
        project = project_list.get(name=name)
    except Project.DoesNotExist:
        raise ValidationError("project does not exist")
        # If you really need to redirect you can
        return redirect("/your-url/")

    return render(request, 'main_projects.html', {'name': name, 'project_list': project_list, 'project': project, 'table': table})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this was fantastic solution to my problem you explained it very well and solved more then one problem. To clarify all I needed was to see if a url matched a model so aka 'https://mywebsite.com/projects/mymodelname' what was happening was if i typed 'https://mywebsite.com/projects/randomname' it would still make the page. Now with your options it worked better for me. I ended up using the get_object_or_404 and did not need to do the try and catch .

Comment: I also wish I could up vote this because this also improved the rest of my code, I have always been bad at optimization and was going to have to go back through to do this but with this I think I can use it with other functions to do some clean up and for that I cant thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an if statement inside your template

```html
{% if issueticket1 %}
  ~Do the Normal things~
{% else %}
  No Match Was Found
{% end if %}
```

you could also do the 404 thing like @kwamito said, that's always good.

Or you could just add and if in the view and a custom redirect like:

- I'm not sure 100% on how this is supposed to work, so just gonna throw two potential redirects in there

```py
@login_required(login_url='login_register')
def project_page(request, name):

  projectMatches = Project.objects.filter(name=name)
  if not projectMatches.count():
    # No Projects
    redirect('errorpage')

  # Note: .first() - it will be the Object or None
  issueticket1 = Issue.objects.filter(related_project__name__exact=name).first()
  if not issueticket1:
    # No Tickets
    redirect('errorpage')

  table = IssueTable(issueticket1)
  project_list = {}

  for p in projectMatches:
    project_list = {'id': p.project_id, 'startdate': p.start_date,
                    'enddate': p.end_date, 'description': p.description}
  return render(request, 'main_projects.html', {'name': name, 'project_list': project_list, 'project': project, 'table': table})
```

Eitherway you should probably use Project.objects.filter() instead of looping through all of them and manually checking names (make the db do that)

---

### Edit

So it depends on what you are using **assigned_users** for..

If you are showing the Assigned users *with* the project, it's best to just loop through them in the template

###### view.py

- Instead of Manually creating + Packing the project_list, just pass the whole QuerySet to the template (it's **a lot** less work)

```py
@login_required(login_url='login_register')
def project_page(request, name):

  # removed for space

  #  for p in projectMatches:
  #    project_list = {'id': p.project_id, 'startdate': p.start_date,
  #                    'enddate': p.end_date, 'description': p.description}

  data = {
    'name': name,
    'project_list': projectMatches,
    'project': project,
    'table': table
    }
  return render(request, 'main_projects.html', data)

# If you are dead set on using a dictonary for project_list, try out:
project_list = projectMatches.values()
# project_list = [
#    {'project_id': '{project_id0}', 'start_date': '{start_date0}', 'end_date': '{end_date0}', 'description': '{description0}'},
#    {'project_id': '{project_id1}', 'start_date': '{start_date1}', 'end_date': '{end_date1}', 'description': '{description1}'},
# ]
```

###### main_projects.html

```html
<!-- HTML / Template -->
{% for i in project_list %}
  <!-- i is the entire Project Object! -->

  Project ID: {{i.project_id}}<br>
  Start Date: {{i.start_date}}<br>
  End Date: {{i.end_date}}<br>
  Desc: {{i.description}}<br>
  <hr>

  Assigned Users:<br>
  {% for u in i.assigned_users_list.all %}
    {{u}}<br>
  {% endfor %}
  <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

But lets say you wanted to filter out Assigned User that have 'completed' their job for the project, just create a model method and call it in the template

- This assumes you ditched the manual dictionary packing

###### models.py

```py
class Project(models.Model):
  project_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

  assigned_users_list = models.ManyToManyField('assigned_users', blank=True)

  def users_with_open_tasks(self):
    return self.assigned_users_list.filter(completed=False)

  def usersnames_with_open_tasks(self):
    return self.assigned_users_list.filter(completed=False).values_list('user__username', flat=True)
```

###### main_projects.html

```html
<!-- HTML / Template -->
{% for i in project_list %}
  <!-- i is the entire Project Object! -->

  Project ID: {{i.project_id}}<br>
  Start Date: {{i.start_date}}<br>
  End Date: {{i.end_date}}<br>
  Desc: {{i.description}}<br>
  <hr>

  Assigned Users:<br>
  {% for u in i.assigned_users_list.all %}
    {{u}}<br>
  {% endfor %}
  <hr>

  Users with Open Tasks:<br>
  {% for u in i.users_with_open_tasks %}
    {{u}}<br>
  {% endfor %}
  <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: One more question, i also have a many to many with in the projects model that links to a custom user model called assigned_users. How would I do a filter for that to show the assigned users so I am not looping through it  in my template.

Comment: I've added an edit.. idk either way you're going to be looping through the assigned users in the template, but hopefully you find some of that useful

Comment: Thank you for the edit that will be useful for other things, for what I was trying to do I found a cheaty solution by using django tables 2 and passing in my own template to make it look like an unordered list. It might be clunky but now my views.py and templates are now void of loops and I have already noticed improvements.